# google app engine error - c2dm.jar

Tags: google-app-engine

I made a project - app engine connected Android project and then just did debug as local app engine connected Android project.

But whenever i tried to press connect button, the Eclipse showed me a message - the jar file c2dm.jar has no source attachment. - i didn't change anything in a code generated

I don't know what i have to do to solve this problem.

I'm just following this practice - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U.
 please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you missing this Jar from your project build path
Try this:

right click on your project > properties > java build path > libraries > add external jars >
than add the c2dm.jar that you will download from here :
http://code.google.com/p/cloud-tasks-io/source/browse/trunk/CloudTasks-Android/lib/c2dm.jar?r=5